# 「投票制と、Minorityと、」其処に　内在する、皆様の　意図に付いて。

Tags: 討議, サポート

投票制を　用いられていますが、
投票では　Minorityの、
括りだしを　防げませんよね？
"

Minorityに付いては、

一定　留意されている、
ものと　思いますが。
"

反して、

投票を　尊重される、
理由は　何故ですか？
"

もしかして、

システムを　継承している、
都合上とかで、
逃れられないのですか？
"

勿論、

留意された　発言も、
実際　見られるようですし、

Minorityを　生み出す、
事は、
忌避されて　いるのですよね？

Comment: nouble さん、 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3587/3 にて編集のロールバックを行われましたが、こちらどのような意図によるものでしょうか。たとえば [討議] タグは実際討議であるため付けたままにしたいのですが……。

Comment: 並記記載こそに、意図が　ありました故、戻させて　頂きました。

Comment: すいません、よく分かりませんでした。[このコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3587/%e6%8a%95%e7%a5%a8%e5%88%b6%e3%81%a8-minority%e3%81%a8/3588?noredirect=1#comment3508_3588)によると私はこの質問の意図を理解できていないようですのでせめてタイトルだけでも自己完結したものにしていただきたいのですが……。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask にあるように、具体的な問題をまとめたタイトルにしていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 私こそが、
"
失態を　働きます、
誤ります、しくじります。
"
"
ですので、
"
お詫びは　私の、
身に　余る、
ものと　思いますよ、
"
"
此は、
"
わびあう　事を、
忌避する　ものでは、
ありませんが、
"
ご互い様という　事で、
如何ですか？

Comment: ここでいうMinorityとはどのような立場の人たちですか？具体的な例題があるとわかりやすいと思います。

Comment: keitaro_so様、
"
ご質問　有り難うございます。
"
"
敢えて、
"
説明を　求められるとは、
展開が　難しいですね、
"
間違えていたら　済みませんね、
"
マジョリティーの　反対語、
マジョリティーを　被る、
他マイノリティーに、
意見を　押し殺される、
もの達、
とか、
"
暫時は　させて、
頂いて　構いませんか？
"
"
後日、
"
問題を　感じましたら、
加筆、訂正を、
させて　頂きたい。

Comment: この質問に「より詳細な情報、もしくは明確さが必要である」としてクローズ票を投じます。投票による少数者への影響を心配されている質問かと思いましたが、コメントを読む限りそうではないようです。また、回答への投票を見る限り似たような解釈をされている方が他にもいそうです。したがってこちらのご質問はもう少し詳細な情報を追加し、ご質問の意図がより明確になるようにしていただきたいです。たとえば、実際に困っている場面などの具体的な内容を追加していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: マイノリティの対義語であるならば、nekketsuuu様の回答で十分満たされていると思いました。念のための「社会のマイノリティの話」と「このサイトは投票による多数決によりきまるわけではない。

Comment: 良い質問は少数派であっても残される」社会のマイノリティは恐らく念のために言及されているだけで大事なことは後半の文章かと

Answer (score 7):

スタック・オーバーフローはプログラミングに関する Q&A サイトであり、投票はあくまで技術的な正当性や個々人にとって役に立ったかの指標として使われています。このため、一般的に言われる社会制度の恩恵を受けづらい社会的少数者という意味での「マイノリティ」とは別軸のものです。社会的少数者に対するハラスメントが関心事であれば、投票制度とは離れますが、[スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)をご覧ください。

また、技術的に少数の人々にしか役に立たない Q&A であっても、その Q&A が良い Q&A であるならば残されます。回答が複数あり、その中にすごく狭いスコープの人にしか役立たない回答があったとしても、プラス投票されているならば残ります。スタック・オーバーフローではむしろ、このように複数の回答の存在を許すことで、ナレッジベースとして役に立ちやすい Q&A を作っています。

スタック・オーバーフローにおける投票は多数決ではありません。つまり、特定の回答が過半数の支持を得たからといって覇権を握る訳ではありません。こういった意味で、投票によってマジョリティだけが残るといったことは起こらないようになっており、ご心配されているようなことは起こりづらくなっています。

Comment: 申し訳ないか、質問趣旨外の　投稿は、お控え願えないか？

Comment: もしこの回答が nouble さんの疑問に答えていないのだとすれば、私はこの質問を誤読しているようです。質問文を編集して、より詳細に書いていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 申し訳ない、此以上　簡潔に、表しようが　ありません。

Comment: 其れと、もしかしてですが　人称関係を、混同されて　いませんか？

Comment: nekketsuuu様、
"
ご指南に　沿い、
タイトルを　変えてみました、
此方で　如何でしょう？